# How to pass arguments to mix browserify compiled file

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, laravel-elixir

I'm using laravel elixir to compile my js files

This is in my gulpfile.js

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserify([
        './compile.js'
        ],
        '../public/build.js'
    );
});
```

Question: In the compile.js is it possible to have something like:

```
var a = require('./views/a/component.vue');
if(custom_variable_passed_from_gulpfile_task){ 
    var b = require('./views/b/component.vue');
}
```

The simple solution is to make another compile.js file for the second situation.. But I really don't want to modify both files everytime I have to do something.
I can't find anything for mix.browserify in which to pass arguments to that file..